# Onclick "run a function" using external javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I created a simple project in which I click on a button then another button should be created(button 2) and the previous button should be disappeared and this works fine.
But when I click on button 2 then a particular function should be executed. I am stuck here.

> ```
> It says cannot set property to null.
> ```

```js
function myFunction1() {
  var x = document.createElement("BUTTON");
  var t = document.createTextNode("button 2");
x.setAttribute('id','bt2');
  x.appendChild(t);
  document.body.appendChild(x);

var a= document.getElementById('bt1');  
a.style.display='none';

}
var item = document.getElementById('bt2');
item.onclick = myFunction;
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0].style.backgroundColor = "lime";
    }
```

```html
<button id= 'bt1' onclick="myFunction1();">
 button 1
</button>
```

Comment: Actually item1 is null, since there is no #bt2 element in the example until you click the button1. So you can't assign the property onclick to a null reference.

Comment: I understand any alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to set the `onclick` property to an element when it doesn't exist yet in the DOM (it will be created after you click the button 1), so move the final code inside the `myFunction1`, after the creation of the second button.

```js
function myFunction1() {
  var b = document.body;
  var x = document.createElement("button");
  var t = document.createTextNode("button 2");

  x.id = 'bt2';
  x.appendChild(t);
  b.appendChild(x);

  var btt1 = document.getElementById('bt1');  
  btt1.style.display='none';

  var btt2 = document.getElementById('bt2');
  btt2.addEventListener('click', function() {
    b.style.backgroundColor = "lime";
  });
}
```

```html
<button id= 'bt1' onclick="myFunction1();">
 button 1
</button>
```

Comment: What if I want to show that hidden button again